# GraphQL: Variable is used by anonymous query but not declared

Tags: graphql

I am new to GraphQL. I have a query, but it shows error message of "Variable is used by anonymous query but not declared".

```
{
   "query":"{customers(first: 1, query: $input) {edges{node {addresses{ id }}}}}",
   "variables":{
      "input":{
         "id":"gid://shopify/Customer/5044061470926"
      }
   }
}
```

Can I get some help what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Answer (score 15):

The error is correct. Your query is

```
{
  customers(first: 1, query: $input) {
    edges{
      node {
        addresses{ 
          id 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and `$input` is indeed not declared, so GraphQL has no idea what it is supposed to be or how to link it up with your `variables` values.

You'll need to do

```
query ($input: <THE_TYPE>!) {
  customers(first: 1, query: $input) {
    edges{
      node {
        addresses{ 
          id 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know your API schema, so you'll have to replace `<THE_TYPE>` with whatever type is defined in your API schema.